# Angular routerLink - what is correct syntax when you want to add extra url text?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I have a component that outputs  links correctly with appropriate href url location (notice `[routerLink]="card.id"`, `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/my-cards/DmJHJJA1e77fEEImKBju`):

```
        <a
            *ngFor="let card of cards; let i = index"
            class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-between"
            [routerLink]="card.id"
            routerLinkActive="active"
        >
            <div class="d-flex flex-column card-info-container">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{card.name}}</h4>
                <p class="mb-1">{{card.description}}</p>
            </div>
            <img [src]="card.imagePath" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="max-width: 50px;">
        </a>
```

I have another route set up like this:

```
{
    path: ':id/edit',
    component: CardEditComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
}
```

So what I am trying to do is in the component  tag above is link directly to this route/component. I changed the [routerLink] syntax to what you see below and got this url `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/my-cards/NaN`

```
[routerLink]="card.id/edit"
```

It's clear that I cannot update the routerLink as I did - is this possible at all to do via syntax in the template only? Or must I have an onclick event to redirect as needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `routerLink = "{{card.id}}/edit"`

Comment: Interesting - does this work? When I tried `[routerLink] = "{{myVar}}"` it gave me the error ***[Angular] Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected***

Comment: Ah, yes I see - it works without `[]` around ***routerLink***. Worthy of many points!

Comment: @RichardMatsen yeah, ```[]``` is for binding from a value in the parent component to an ```@Input()``` in the child component. It allows to pass objects.```{{}}``` is for binding strings in properties and HTML.

Comment: So routerLink is a directive, but it ***also*** has an `@input` named routerLink, which takes a javascript expression when using `[routerLink]` or an Angular template expression when using `routerLink`. That's my take on it. ... Ref [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0cb4f12a7a57087ec4e8329a04d5dfc430764b45/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts).

Comment: @RichardMatsen No matter what our property is and it's just angular template syntax 2 way binding, i think?!

Comment: I don't think so, because see the error I reported above. `{{something}}` is part of the template expression, but it doesn't work when routerLink is defined with square brackets.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your `routerLink` as follows

`[routerLink]="[card.id, 'edit']"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing route parameters then you need to have the route name first and then the params as ['routeName', parameter..]

But here since the route name itself includes the parameter, you need to concatenate both and use it as string.

`[routerLink] = [ {{card. Id}} + '/edit']`